# Can't find the verb for "move on tentacles"

Tags: word-request

I need a verb for **"move on tentacles"**? Something like walk or travel on tentacles.

There isn't such a thing as **"to tentacle"** and i can't find another word that would convey this meaning.

Comment: I think the closest you can get it is "to slither."

Comment: @LawrenceC So an octopus can slither on its tentacles?

Comment: *slither on its tentacles* sounds appropriate to this US English speaker.  Of course people do sometimes just say that octopuses "walk" or "crawl".

Comment: Usual would be  **moves** or **crawls**.  **Slithers** is more wriggling, undulating, snakelike.

Comment: If it helps, [Land snails move by gliding along on their muscular foot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_snail#Physical_characteristics), while [Octopuses crawl, swim or walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octopus#Locomotion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no single word that has consensus to describe using tentacles to move on a solid surface. Not only is there no word that means *specifically* that, but there's no word that everyone agrees is *the* word for that.

***Crawl***, ***slither*** or ***walk*** can all work, and give different implications about the way in which the tentacles are being used.

To *walk* on tentacles would be to use them like legs.

To *crawl* on tentacles would not be to use them quite like legs, not so articulated, but still probably to be moving one's body up and down while one moved, pushing up on one tentacle after another.

To *slither* on tentacles suggests all of them remain equally on the ground at all times, and in very much the same position relative to the body.